# How to init a struct in swift 4.2

Tags: swift, struct

What I want:
To initialise a struct before use. But I really don't know how, even after a lot of trying and searching.

Example of the struct:

```
struct Person: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}
```

I want to use this struct global in my script. The way I think it would have been is like this (but it does not work, because of line 3):

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let personExample: Person()

    func configure(person: Person) {
        self.personExample = person
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(self.personExample)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you lack a fundamental understanding in `=` vs `:`, and what the `()` syntax means. I would advise you read the [Swift Language Guide.](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID310)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will read it trough.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax here is simply incorrect:

```
let personExample: Person()
```

What you meant was this:

```
let personExample: Person
```

`Person()` is the result of calling `init()`, which is a value, not a type, and isn't a valid initializer for this type anyway. `Person` is the type, which is what you want for a declaration.

However, what you've written here doesn't quite line up with the description. If you want a "global," this is actually an instance variable. What you may have meant here is the following:

```
var personExample = Person(name: "Bob", age: 21)
```

That would assign `personExample` to that value (and through type inference, assign the type to `Person`). I've used `var` here because `configure(person:)` tries to modify it.

You also may be confused about initialization of instance variables in view controllers when using storyboards. If that's your issue (for example, you're seeing errors about personExample not being set during initialization), you'll need to explain a little more about your situation and we can help you with that.

Answer (score -1):

You need

```
 var personExample: Person?

func configure(person: Person) {
    self.personExample = person
}
```

---

first this `let personExample: Person()` is an incorrect syntax and if you changed to

```
var personExample: Person
```

it'll raise an error as it must be initated in the vc init methods , also if you don't implement coding , remove `: Decodable {`

Comment: Thanks! You helped me a lot, not the whole fix. But I found a nasty solution I think. I did the `var personExample: Person?` part. But now I need to do the following: `label.text = personExample?.name` I don't know if its nasty, it's my second day coding in swift.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that this vc will be configured before present ? if so directly make it `var personExample: Person!` if not then `label.text = personExample?.name ?? "Default"`

Comment: @UNTITLED.PNG `label.text = personExample?.name`  is perfectly fine as text property is optional String as well